# Get the variable from ejs or javascript(browser) file to the Express

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

How do I take a value from ejs or javascript file to ExpressJS ? I have ejs and javascript files in my project. Both of these files have the same variable, so I need to find a way to get that variable from one of them. Problem is, when I try to import ejs file, I get syntax errors because ejs file has HTML tags such as div, body, script, etc. For the Javascript file, it has 18,000 lines and it was written for browsers. Meaning, I get thousands of errors like *window is not defined*, *blabla is not a function*, *x is not defined*, etc.

I tried to export them with module.exports, when I try to import it on server file like `'const example = require('./x/index.ejs)'` then I get the errors for both of the files.

```
// The thing that I want an example

// Server side
const x = require('./x/file)'
app.get('/havaist/live', (req, res) => {
   console.log(x.theWantedVariable)
})

// Ejs
<body>
<div> <h1> Hey there. </h1> </div>
<script>
.
..
...
....
     here the data that needs get fetched from ExpressJS.
....
...
..
.
</script>
</body>

//Javascript
.
..
...
....
     here the data that needs get fetched from ExpressJS.
....
...
..
.
```

```
ERRORS:
When trying to import EJS:

/home/nimda/Documents/Devspace/hikvision-api/views/index.ejs:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <body onload="getCameraNo();realplay();">
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)

When trying to import JAVASCRIPT:

/home/nimda/Documents/Devspace/hikvision-api/views/dist/jsPlugin-1.2.0.min.js:10
})(window, function() {
   ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nimda/Documents/Devspace/hikvision-api/views/dist/jsPlugin-1.2.0.min.js:10:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nimda/Documents/Devspace/hikvision-api/server.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
```

Comment: What is your actual real world usecase? What is the code supposed to do, and which value do you want to share between client/server and why?

Comment: It's gonna be a service for our mobile & web application. Currently, I made an API that shows some information about our devices. I want to add one more line to API that I made, and that will show the variable that needs to get import to ExpressJS. And that variable comes from a request and that request getting processed in JS file which is 18,000 lines and variables & function names stand by letters that mean its impossible to copy the whole process to ExpressJS.

Comment: "18.000 lines" just sounds wrong. You should split up that into a modular strucutre, then you can reuse some modules on the backend too. Also it is still  unclear why that variable has to be sent to the backend

Comment: As I said, it is impossible to understand it because function names and variable names standing by letters. It is necessary and uneditable file.

Answer (score 0):

Send an ajax POST request from the ejs file and grab that value from the express file.

Comment: Yes thats what I did, but honestly its not really ethic:/

Comment: @OnurÖzkan What do you mean by its not really ethic?